# Post an array in input elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, post, arrays

Basically I've got textboxes called dimension[0][scale], dimension[0]width etc.

How do i pass the the elements 'dimension' as an array? I've tried `$('input[name=dimension]').serialize()` and doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Can you post the textboxes, the markup that is?

Comment: <input type='text' name='dimension[0][scale]' />

Answer (score 0):

Is this wat you want to do:

```
var dimArr = $.makeArray($("input[name^='dimension']"));
for(var i = 0; i < dimArr.length; i++) {        
  //this displays name of checkbox elements stored as array
  alert(dimArr[i].name);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to serialize data for an AJAX request in jQuery, just serialize the entire form:

```
var formData = $('#RateAddForm').serialize();
```